# SQL sum total each column in last row

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum, rollup

I wish SQL for SUM each column(IPO and UOR) in TOTAL in second last. And GRAND TOTAL(Sum IPO + UOR) in the last one. Thank you so much

```
No  Code   IPO UOR
----------------------
1   D173    1   0
2   D176    3   0
3   D184    1   1
4   D185B   1   0
5   D187    1   2
6   F042    3   0
7   ML004   12  3
8   TTPMC   2   0
9   Z00204  1   0
------------------
TOTAL (NOS) 25  6
-------------------------
GRAND TOTAL (NOS)   31
```

Here is my code, :

```
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN IPOType = 'IPO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IPO,
SUM(CASE WHEN IPOType = 'UOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UOR  
FROM IPO2018 
GROUP BY OriProjNo
```

it can show like this

```
No  Code   IPO UOR
----------------------
1   D173    1   0
2   D176    3   0
3   D184    1   1
4   D185B   1   0
5   D187    1   2
6   F042    3   0
7   ML004   12  3
8   TTPMC   2   0
9   Z00204  1   0
------------------
```

Comment: use `group by rollup` which exists in SQL Server but not MySQL (so do not include tags that do not apply to your question)

Comment: See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918878/how-to-sum-column-wise-and-row-wise-in-sql-server/47919195#47919195 I showed there how to use `GROUP BY` with `GROUPING SETS`

Comment: That is not the output from that code.  You don't identify the database.

Comment: @Paparazzi it's my code from sql server database.

Comment: Again.  That is not the output from that code. You don't identify the database.  VTC

Comment: @Paparazzi what??

Comment: Can't help you.  My statement is clear.

Comment: @Paparazzi it's up to you.

Comment: Why do you want these totals in your script?  Where are you presenting the query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to leave totals and sub-totals to whatever tool you are presenting your data in, as they will be able to handle the formatting with significantly more ease.  In addition, your desired output does not have the same number of columns (`Grand Total` row only has one numeric) so even if you did shoehorn this in to the same dataset, the column headings wouldn't make sense.

That said, you can return group totals via the `with rollup` statement.  This will provide an additional row with the aggregate totals for the group.  Where there is more than one group in your data, you will get a sub-total row for each group and a total row for the entire dataset:

```
declare @t table(c nvarchar(10),t nvarchar(3));
insert into @t values ('D173','IPO'),('D176','IPO'),('D176','IPO'),('D176','IPO'),('D184','IPO'),('D184','UOR'),('D185B','IPO'),('D187','IPO'),('D187','UOR'),('D187','UOR'),('F042','IPO'),('F042','IPO'),('F042','IPO'),('TTPMC','IPO'),('TTPMC','IPO'),('Z00204','IPO'),('ML004','UOR'),('ML004','UOR'),('ML004','UOR'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO'),('ML004','IPO');

select row_number() over (order by grouping(c),c) as n
    ,case when grouping(c) = 1 then 'TOTAL (NOS)' else c end as c
    ,sum(case when t = 'IPO' then 1 else 0 end) as IPO
    ,sum(case when t = 'UOR' then 1 else 0 end) as UOR
from @t
group by c
with rollup
order by grouping(c)
        ,c;
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
| n  |      c      | IPO | UOR |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
|  1 | D173        |   1 |   0 |
|  2 | D176        |   3 |   0 |
|  3 | D184        |   1 |   1 |
|  4 | D185B       |   1 |   0 |
|  5 | D187        |   1 |   2 |
|  6 | F042        |   3 |   0 |
|  7 | ML004       |  12 |   3 |
|  8 | TTPMC       |   2 |   0 |
|  9 | Z00204      |   1 |   0 |
| 10 | TOTAL (NOS) |  25 |   6 |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+
```